# SOLVED - Big Query Cannot read repeated field of type STRUCT as optional STRUCT Field

Tags: json, mongodb, google-bigquery

I have MongoDB data that is extracted to Big Query using Google Cloud Function. We use partition table that is separated with date. There is one field (`location`) in collections that change from object (RECORD) to array (unexpected). we change it to object (RECORD) again and there is error when extracting this field. the error message is:

`Cannot read repeated field of type STRUCT as optional STRUCT Field: location`

I thought it is because there is partition table that still array data types. after we backfill all the partition. the error still same. any idea guys?

[image: Query]

[image: Table]

UPDATE: Some of partition table is still in ARRAY, so it have to be changed to RECORD

Comment: You are query over several tables. Is the query working, if you only query the last day. `from db_mongodb.SCD2_users_20230219`

Comment: yes it's worked. I think the problem is because of some partition table not RECORD but ARRAY. I will close this thread. thanks

Comment: Hi @OctavianWR if your issue is resolved can please post your answer so that it would be helpful for community members?